# Copy SQL Server Databases Remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, copy, backup, restore

How do I copy one database on one server to the next? I am using SQL Server 2005.  In the past I used Tasks -> Backup then Restore to the new database.  But my server with the database is full and I can't delete anything and SQL Server only appears to allow backups to the local machine.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are the servers running on a domain? I.e., can the account that SQL Server runs on access network shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make the backup using T-SQL directly on a network share:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = '\\AnotherServer\SomeShare\MyDatabase.bak'
```

If you prefer to use SQL Server Management Studio: that's possible as well, but not as easy as the T-SQL version,

Take a look at this:

- [Backup and Restore SQL Server Database to a network shared drive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/06/04/backup-sql-server-database-to-a-share-drive-on-another-server.aspx)
- [SQL Server backup and restore to network drive](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1126/sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-network-drive/)

Comment: That only works if the servers are running on a domain account.

Comment: ...or on `NT AUTHORITY/NETWORKSERVICE`.